# Reading Columns From File Into Lists

Tags: java, list, file, io

I have a  txt file which has a dynamic number of columns of strings in it.  Every day the number of columns changes. How can I read each column into a separate List (in Java) without knowing how many columns there are?
example text as per request:

```
129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1    129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1  
129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1    129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1  
129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1    129.64.58.1      129.64.58.1
```

(tab deliminated)

Comment: ...by implementing a FileReader that scans for a number of columns first and then adjusts accordingly

Comment: Post your sample txt structure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FileReader` to read the file line by line, breaking on your tab delimiter, and adding the columns to a `List`.

A `BufferedReader` is a convenient `FileReader` implementation to read in a line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path\\to\\file.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();
String[] columns = line.split("\t");
```

Now you know how many columns you have, and what's in the columns. Then, as you required, make `columns.length` number of `List`s and add each element in `columns` into its appropriate `List`.